# golang defining dict like python with and appending value to list in dict

Tags: python, data-structures, struct, go

I am new to go and trying to implement python like nested structure as below, I am not able to define the empty dict/map in golang that can have list of specific struct/classobj and while iterating through the data I am not able to append items in map/dict ... I will really appreciate any help on this ... Thanks

```
items = [
    ("item1", someObj1),
    ("item2", someObj2),
    ("item3", someObj3),
    ("item3", someObj5),
    ("item1", someObj4),
]

rectors = {}
for item, obj in items:
    try:
        rectors[item].append(obj)
    except KeyError:
        rectors[item] = [obj]

print rectors
# OUTPUT: {'item2': [someObj2], 'item3': [someObj3, someObj5], 'item1': [someObj1, someObj4]}
```

Comment: I'd like to recommend the Go Tour http://tour.golang.go which explains all this.

Comment: Thanks @Volker will have a look ...

Comment: @Volker link is changed to https://tour.golang.org

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its not quite as clean .. but this does roughly what you want and should get you started on the right path:

```
type someObj struct {
}

func main() {
    items := map[string][]someObj{
        "item1": []someObj{someObj{}},
        "item2": []someObj{someObj{}},
        "item3": []someObj{someObj{}},
    }

    items["item1"] = append(items["item1"], someObj{})

    rectors := make(map[string][]someObj)    

    for key, val := range items {
        if obj, exists := rectors[key]; exists {
            rectors[key] = append(obj, val...)
        } else {
            rectors[key] = val
        }
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", rectors)
}
```

Output:

```
map[item3:[{}] item1:[{} {}] item2:[{}]]
```

The main difference being .. you can't initialize the map *and* alter an item with a key that already exists (as you appear to be doing in your example with `item1` being appended during initialization). So that becomes an extra step after the initialization of the map. You could always just do:

```
"item1": []someObj{someObj{}, someObj{}},
```

.. but that didn't seem to be the same as what you were doing.

<kbd>[See it on the Go playground](http://play.golang.org/p/HrJKBCWJi7)</kbd>

Comment: when ranging over items, you want to check if the key exists in rectors, and in this case, do an append instead of an assignment

Comment: Good point .. must have skipped over that. Awkward. I'll fix it up.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead really appreciate the effort, the problem is I don't know how many items I am gonna get, so defining map with set no. of keys is not really what I want, I want an empty map that can populated depending on data I receive.. Thanks again for the effort

Comment: @Aedil I have updated my answer. Notice the `append` operation in the loop now. Apologies for missing that important part :/

Comment: @Aedil You may also want to look at [this Go blog article about arrays, slices and append](http://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: @Aedil Another approach would be do something like: http://play.golang.org/p/PLK2YV-vNV